# Reload selected post in multiple post query with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a site that basically shows projects and then for each project lists all events connected to it ordered by the start date. To achieve this for each single project (post type - project) there is a query within the project listing all events (post type - event) below it. I'm looking for a way to on click of a trigger reload just the targeted single events content. Here is my query

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php 
 // get posts
 $posts = get_posts(array(
                'post_type'         => 'event',
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'meta_key'          => 'date_start',
                'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
                'order'             => 'ASC'
            ));

if( $posts ): ?>
<ul class="events">

<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
setup_postdata( $post )
?>

<li class="event">

<p><?php the_title(); ?></p>

<?php
$date = get_field('date_start', false, false);
$date = new DateTime($date);
?>

<div class="date-start">
<?php echo $date->format('j M Y'); ?>
</div>

<div class="refresh">
Reload just this event without refreshing page
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</li>
</ul>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What would be the best way to implement this ideally using Ajax with reload spinner in place of the single events li until loaded.

Comment: First thing first, you have got a lot of problem in your code. You don't have `endwhile;`, you are setting `posts_per_page => -1`, which will return all the post so no post will be there  to get from ajax an epic fail, you are using `get_post()` inside loop where your post arguments never change is  another huge fail as `get_post` will be used as long as the loop continues.What is this? Did you run this code once?? Please try to fix it first.

Comment: Hi @BikashWaiba - apologies I didn't include the starting loop (updated now) - so basically this is on single.php which displays the main project, I have the fist main call to get the project, close it then do another call outside the loop to list all my events - I'm using -1 for posts per page, because as I say I am listing every event below the the project title. I then want to be able to trigger a refresh on each individual event that is called in my foreach.

Comment: so, you are using `single.php` for listing along with showing single post  and you want to update single post view via ajax. Is that it?

Comment: Yes that's correct